# How to configure node js datasource.json in aws linux machine

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp, loopbackjs, loopback

> Hi, I've created on sample application with nodejs and loopback. when
>   i tried with "db" memory its working. When i added lb datasource its
>   throwing mysql error. Kindly help me how to solve it.

### datasource.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mysql": {
    "host": "ec2-52-35-183-50.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "port": "3307",
    "url": "",
    "database": "medola",
    "password":"xxyyxx@123",
    "name": "mysql",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
}
```

### Stacktrace:

```
Connection fails: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.24.147:3307 It will be retried for the next request. events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.24.147:3307
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at MySQL.connect (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:89:17)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:43:28)
    at DataSource.setup (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:352:19)
    at new DataSource (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:121:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:355:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:440:19)
    at EventEmitter.app.dataSource (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:235:14)
    at /home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:190:9
    at /home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:281:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachKeyedObject (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:280:20)
    at setupDataSources (/home/ec2-user/medola/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:180:3)
```

Comment: Are you using EC2 instance to host that MySQL database?

Comment: It's hard to answer without additional information. According to host link, your MySQL db is on EC2. Where did you deploy your Loopback application? Is it on another EC2 instance? Maybe you don't have internet access enabled from that instance or port 3307 is closed on MySQL instance. Can you provide more information about your setup?

Comment: @IvanSchwarz i have installed xampp on ec2 instance, it contains mysql inbuilt. when i up my xampp it will start mysql on port 3306. In my local pc i have installed the same for configuring db with my datasource.

Comment: Your datasource configuration points to port 3307, but it should be 3306 if mysql runs on that port. Second thing is that you have to open 3306 port on your EC2 instance if you are targeting that port from your local computer. Also make sure that your MySql server accepts remote connections.

Comment: @A.Z. yeah, when it doesn't worked. i only manually changed the port from 3306 default port to 3307 port. I allowed all the traffic on my aws instance. Am able to connect to the mysql through the EC2 link through phpmyadmin. Only its failing on code to connect through datasource.json code. Also i've made changes on mysql config to allow remote connections

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have the correct privileges set up in your IAM role. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.html